# Equivalent of StructKeyList() for struct value

Tags: forms, coldfusion, coldfusion-2016

`StructKeyList()` will give me list of struct key with comma delimited. Now I need to get struct value with comma delimited. Right now this is what I'm doing to get value

```
<cfloop collection="#form#" item="key" >
    #form[key]#,
</cfloop>
```

How can I get list of value from struct without loop? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you know the name of your key, you can just pick off the value. Something like `form.myfieldname`. I don't understand why the loop is a problem.

Comment: Also, what is your overall objective here? You're apparently iterating through a list of form fields, but why? There may be a better way to solve your bigger issue.

Comment: @Shawn I have dynamic form data to insert with mysql. So I was wondering whether there is a function I could use directly with my `insert` query. Right now I'm working with  `INSERT INTO `student` (
   #ListQualify(StructKeyList(form),"`")#
 ) 
 VALUES
   (
  #ListQualify(val,"'")#
   ) ;`

Comment: I'd be _very_ careful about SQL injection with a scheme like that. It's not usually a good idea to insert data directly into a database from form values.

Comment: By "dynamic form data", do you mean that you have a list of fields that may or may not be in your form submission, that the names of the fields are dynamically generated or something else?

Comment: `list of fields that may or may not be in your form submission` this is what I meant.

Comment: yeah I think this won't work with `cfqueryparam`.

Comment: Using tags, no. But I think it's possible to build this query string with parameterized inputs in cfscript. So do you know what form will be submitting to this INSERT or is this a catch-all INSERT query?

Comment: there's only one form will be using this query.

Comment: Yeah, I second the warning about sql injection. Using raw client supplied values in a query is **very risky**. If you must construct a list, be sure to use cfscript so you can protect the query with parameters, ie addParam(). Otherwise, the query becomes a sql injection opening just waiting to be exploited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I go through your problem. As per my knowledge is not possible to get list of value in structure within single functions. We have to loop the key and get the value of each. But I can give a solution for to get struct value with comma delimited.

```
<cfset strNew = {"a":"10","b":20,"c":30}>
```

Here strNew is my sample structure.

```
 <cfset  myList = ''>
<cfloop collection="#strNew#" item="key" >
    <cfset myList = listappend(myList,structfind(strNew,key))>
</cfloop>
<cfdump var="#myList#" />
```

Here I've loop over the structure keys and find the value of an particular key and append that in to and list by using listappend and structfind functions.

So you no need to  put like #structure[key]#,In your end of comma(,) is also added the last value of key too. For example your code should return 10,20,30,.

So you no need to do like that. use structfind and listappend you can avoid end of the comma also. Hope it's help you.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using CF2016, if you want to avoid a loop, you can always use one of the higher-order functions like `reduce()`.

```
fields = formScope.reduce( function(result, key, value) { 
    result.append(value) ;
    return result ;
}, [] ) ;
```

This takes the struct of your `form` scope (`formscope`) and uses `reduce()` to step through it and take it down to a single value (which is the struct values turned into an array). Then we make the returned array into a list.

```
writeDump( fields.toList() )
```

My full test code is at https://trycf.com/gist/f00cc62cd4631f44070faf8008e6788f/acf2016?theme=monokai

```
<cfscript>
formScope = { 
    empty1 : "" ,
    fieldl : "text1" ,
    field2 : "text2" ,
    empty2 : "" ,
    field3 : "text3" ,
    field4 : "text4" ,
    empty3 : ""
} ; 

fields = formScope?.reduce( function(result, key, value) { 
    len(value) ? result.append(value) : "" ;
    return result ;
}, [] ) ; 

writeDump( fields?.toList() ?: "Form doesn't exist." ) ; 
</cfscript>
```

Giving us: `text2,text3,text4,text1`.

`formScope` is my simulated version of the form fields that would be passed to this page. I use mostly the member function versions of `StructReduce`, `ArrayAppend` and `ArrayToList`. I also use the `initialVal` optional parameter to initialize the reduction's `result` value as an array. I check that the value has a length (I could also trim if needed) before I insert a row in the array, allowing me to remove empty elements from my final list. I also use the safe navigation operator (`?.`) to do some basic validation to make sure the elements exist (like if the form didn't pass or the reduction produced invalid results) and to make it more error-resistant.

*NOTE: I believe that can be taken back to be compatible with CF11, when `ArrayReduce` was introduced.*

https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-s/structreduce.html
http://ryanguill.com/functional/higher-order-functions/2016/05/18/higher-order-functions.html
https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-a-b/arraytolist.html